# Questions on subdivision

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm following this anvil tutorial and the first time I got the result right after subdivision.

[image]

Then I redid it second and third time yet it came out like this. I think I did exactly the same everytime. Already merged by distance.
[image]

Comment: hmm, could you share your blend file so that we can look more closely? It looks a bit weird, like it is flipped so maybe it is flipped normals, but there is probably something more

Comment: @MikoCG sure uploaded!

Comment: Try selecting all verts with A, and then Alt + N -> Recalculate Outside

Comment: @AllenSimpson been there too Q__Q

Comment: Firstly I am not sure what version you sent me, the model that I have opened looks totally different from images you have shown us... next thing, the problem is that in the version that you sent me there are still duplicit vertices, but simple M -> by distance is not enough, you need to use higher distance (there were 34 duplicates)... last thing is the bottom face, it is ngon of too many vertices with circle cut in it... you need to cut it into more smaller faces to make it work

Comment: @MikoCG right it's the bottom face!!  i didnt do anything the first time but it was cut into smaller faces thats why it worked. thx a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the main difference is this:
[image]
[image]

In your better attempt you had this subdivision in that face, making the adjacent face become a polygon with 5 sides, which is usually not good but in this case forced the subdiv to add more loops in the vertical faces. I'm not sure that's case, it's just a guess.

Anyway, I'd add a support loop here:

[image]

Or even more than one:

[image]

Comment: +1 Also @OP inset the bottom face, if that thing is a giant N-Gon it probably isn't helping things either.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots it looks to me like in your better attempt, your hard edge contained those supporting edge loops. This will affect your subdivision result.

[image]

Comment: hmm i think i added those lines after the right subdiversion effect tho to sharpen the edges a bit